# Relate two averages to find a probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

I would like to "relate" two arithmetic averages and then use them in Poisson. I currently already use a method, but i'm sure we can do better and that there is a better way. I currently sum the two averages, then divide by two, then use the result in Poisson.

In the championship matches played so far, `Team_A` and `Team_B` have never clashed against each other, but so far the average number of `goals scored` by Team_A is `1.40`; Instead the average number of `goals conceded` by Team_B is `1.80`. I would like to calculate how many probabilità there are that Team_A scores 2 goals against Team_B in the next match when the two teams will clash against each other. The two averages are independent, because there is no correlation between the two datasets.

An important observation is that: the goals scored by Team_A against Team_B will be the same as those that Team_B will concede from Team_A.

Is there any better way that can **replace** addition and division by 2? (my Union) and find a value to use in Poisson?

```
TEAM_A__List_Goals = 2, 1, 3, 0, 1
TEAM_A__Total_Goals_Scored = 7
TEAM_A__Number_Match_Played = 5
TEAM_A__Average_Scored = 1.40

TEAM_B__List_Goals = 1, 2, 2, 3, 1
TEAM_B__Total_Goals_Conceded = 9
TEAM_B__Number_Match_Played = 5
TEAM_B__Average_Conceded = 1.8

Union = (TEAM_A__Goals_Scored + TEAM_B__Goals_Conceded) / 2

#POISSON PROBABILITY CALCULATION
two_goals = ((Union ** 2) * 2.7182818284 ** (-Union)) / 2 * 100
```

Thank you all!

Comment: I assume your RV are poisson distributed with $\mathbb{E}(A)=1.4$ and $\mathbb{E}(B)=1.8$. You can now express the probability that A scores atleast two goals as a conditional probability $\mathbb{P}(A \geq 2 | A=B)$.

Comment: @Keine_Maschine In this case, what would the final result (parameter to be inserted in Poisson) be?

Comment: You can calculate the distribution $\mathbb{P}(X=0), \mathbb{P}(X=1), ...$ with $\mathbb{P}(X=i)=\mathbb{P}(A=i|A=B)$. I'm not sure wheter $X$ is still poisson distributed, but that doesn't really matter. If it is you can estimate the parameter for example by regression.

Comment: @Keine_Maschine Is the formula you showed me that of Conditional Probability? Can you show me the numerical result of your formula? (and how to get it). Please :)

Comment: You can google the formula for conditional probability, then you can calculate the distribution of $X$. Example: $\mathbb{P}(X=0)=\mathbb{P}(A=0|A=B)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(A=B=0)}{\mathbb{P}(A=B)}=\frac{\mathbb{P}(A=0) \cdot \mathbb{P}(B=0) }{\mathbb{P}(A=B)}$.   $\mathbb{P}(A=0)$ and $\mathbb{P}(B=0)$ are clear, $\mathbb{P}(A=B)$ is open to calculate. I think you can do this on your own! :)

Comment: @Keine_Maschine Ok :) Are you sure that conditional probability is needed in my case? The conditional probability is the probability that A will occur, knowing that B has already occurred. If you consider the averages, then both A and B have already occurred. If you consider the probability, then neither of the two events has already occurred.

Comment: @Keine_Maschine (I add to the comment above) In conditional probability, the maximum number of occurrence of an event is used. In my case I should use for example 10 which is the maximum number of goals that can be scored or conceded in a match. But 10 is not a certain and certain number, I could also use 6, 7, 8. I don't know this number.

Comment: There is no right or wrong implementation method. You are asking for a model to predict the Goals of Team A against Team B. The approach with conditional probability is how I would model this. Maybe you can solve it different without conditional probability. The event B (which is A=B) always occures as you already observed by yourself. Therefore this construction is reasonable.

Comment: @Keine_Maschine Ok I understand. One last clarification please: why did you say that, after calculating the conditional probability, I will then have to estimate the parameter (to be used in Poisson) through regression? The result of the conditional probability is only one. Regression uses two variables. I don't understand what you mean. Can you explain yourself better? Thank you

Comment: There is no for an upper limit on X. In theory X can take infinitly many, infinitly big values. Probably you want to know how to calculate $\mathbb{P}(A=B)$? Simply as $\mathbb{P}(A=B)=\mathbb{P}(A=B=0)+...+\mathbb{P}(A=B=10)$. From here on I don't think more of my comments add value to this discussion, so pls don't expect anymore answers from me. Good luck with your problem!